# Recursion function for counting the number of digits in a number?

Tags: python, recursion

So I know that this is something simple that can be done without a recursion function but I need to know the backside to this as I can't seem to figure out how to write this using recursion. im using this so far

```
n = int(raw_input("What is n? "))
def digit(n):
    if n< 10:
        return 1
    else:
        new = n/10
        print 1 + digit(new/10)
        return 1 + digit(new/10)

digit(n)
```

Now if I type in a number such as 33 then it outputs 2 but if I do a longer number then it doesn't print it properly and I was unsure as to what exactly it wrong with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  #!/usr/bin/python

  n = int(raw_input("What is n? "))

  def digit(n):
      if n < 10:
          return 1
      else:
          return 1 + digit(n/10)

  print digit(n)
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is,

```
    new = n/10
    return 1 + digit(new/10)
```

You are already dividing the number by 10, in `new = n / 10`, which reduces the last digit and you are again dividing it by 10 before calling `digit`. So, you are ignoring 1 digit in every recursive call.

Instead, you can simply do

```
    return 1 + digit(n / 10)
```

or

```
    new = n / 10
    return 1 + digit(new)
```

Comment: I see how that caused an issue, for some reason im still getting an issue as when I type in a number such as 5443, it printed the numbers
2
3
2
4
2
3
2

Comment: @MrPorba remove the print

Comment: wont that lead it so that nothing is printed at all in the idle window?

Comment: @MrPorba `digit(n)` will print the actual result.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this too.

```py
def counter(number):
    if(number == 0):
        return 0
    return counter(int(number/10)) + 1

number = 1998
print(counter(number)) // it will print 4
```